# Left vs Right linked list, Replace speed

Tags: optimization, linked-list, wolfram-mathematica

There are two obvious ways to structure a linked list in Mathematica, "left":

```
{1, {2, {3, {4, {5, {6, {7, {}}}}}}}}
```

And "right":

```
{{{{{{{{}, 7}, 6}, 5}, 4}, 3}, 2}, 1}
```

These can be made with:

```
toLeftLL = Fold[{#2, #} &, {}, Reverse@#] & ;

toRightLL = Fold[List, {}, Reverse@#] & ;
```

If I use these, and do a simple `ReplaceRepeated` to walk through the linked list, I get drastically different `Timing` results:

```
r = Range[15000];
left = toLeftLL@r;
right = toRightLL@r;

Timing[i = 0; left //. {head_, tail_} :> (i++; tail); i]
Timing[i = 0; right //. {tail_, head_} :> (i++; tail); i]

(* Out[6]= {0.016, 15000} *)

(* Out[7]= {5.437, 15000} *)
```

Why?

Comment: I guess it can be faster because of tail call optimization.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Could you break down the RHS of your `RuleDelayed`. Although I _think_ I sort of see how it walks through the list, it's not entirely clear. Also, if I replace `tail` in the RHS with `tail-tail+tail`, I get an error: `$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>` and need to abort. Why doesn't mma figure out that `tail-tail+tail=tail` and return the same result as before?

Comment: @yoda, for a "left" list, `{head_, tail_} :> (i++; tail)` increments `i` and returns the rest of the linked list, without the first element (head), e.g. `{2, {3, {4, {5, {6, {7, {}}}}}}}` if used on the first list in my question.  I increment `i` simply to prove that this replacement took place 15,000 times in each case.  The pattern `head_` was used only for clarity and could be replaced with `_` just as well.  Since `tail` is a list structure, and  arithmetic operations thread through such trees, you are doing up to 14,999 operations rather than one with each `+` or `-`.

Comment: aah `//.`!! I wasn't careful in noticing it and was trying to wrap my head around how the walk-through is done with `/.` That didn't make much sense! Now that I see it, it's clear! Thanks for the explanation on the second part of the comment.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Just bumped you up to 4k :)

Comment: @yoda oh, it was you!  Thank you! :-)

Comment: Interesting behavior. The stuff you guys come up with keeps me entertained. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ReplaceRepeated` uses `SameQ` to determine when to stop applying the rule.

When `SameQ` compares two lists, it checks lengths, and if the same, then applies `SameQ` to elements from the first to the last. In the case of `left` the first element is an integer, so it is easy to detect distinct lists, while for `right` list the first element is the deeply nested expression, so it needs to traverse it. This is the reason for the slowness.

```
In[25]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[Extract[right, ConstantArray[1, k]] === 
   Extract[right, ConstantArray[1, k + 1]], {k, 0, 15000 - 1}]]

Out[25]= {11.7091708, Null}
```

Now compare this with:

```
In[31]:= Timing[i = 0; right //. {tail_, head_} :> (i++; tail); i]

Out[31]= {5.351, 15000}
```

---

**EDIT** In response to Mr.Wizard's question of options to speed this up. One should write a custom same testings. `ReplaceRepeated` does not provide such an option, so we should use `FixedPoint` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
In[61]:= Timing[i = 0; 
 FixedPoint[(# /. {tail_, _} :> (i++; tail)) &, right, 
  SameTest -> 
   Function[
    If[ListQ[#1] && ListQ[#2] && 
      Length[#1] == 
       Length[#2], (#1 === {} && #2 === {}) || (Last[#1] === 
        Last[#2]), #1 === #2]]]; i]

Out[61]= {0.343, 15000}
```

---

**EDIT2**: Faster yet:

```
In[162]:= Timing[i = 0; 
 NestWhile[Function[# /. {tail_, head_} :> (i++; tail)], right, 
  Function[# =!= {}]]; i]

Out[162]= {0.124, 15000}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `SameQ` is involved here? Turning on tracing of `SameQ` does not show any calls to it: `On[SameQ];`.

Comment: `On[SameQ]` will only shows evaluations of `SameQ` symbol. `ReplaceRepeated` does not call the evaluator for efficiency when determining that `ReplaceRepeated` should terminate.

Comment: That's what I call an author-itative answer

Comment: @Alexey Sacha perhaps is not _thinking_ : http://www.linkedin.com/pub/oleksandr-pavlyk/4/403/39a

Comment: @Sasha Is it possible for a user to define functions which use such functions as `SameQ` without calling the evaluator?

Comment: Interesting!  Is there a way to speed this up?  A different pattern perhaps?

Comment: As I consider this, I realize it is quite far reaching.  Is there a way to affect the evaluation order of SameQ (or its internal counterpart)?  I may have to revise some of my programs in light of this.

Comment: @Alexey No, all user provided code is executed through the evaluator. This is how the language interpreter works.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have given one possibility to speed up the code in my edit to the answer.

Comment: @Sasha Does the evaluator also use `SameQ` to determine whether the evaluation should be finished because the expression does not change anymore?

Comment: @Alexey Evaluator stops when it sees that no transformations apply. It does not need to use the `SameQ`. When a rule has been applied, the entire result gets evaluated until no more rules can be applied. I think this is very nicely written in [Principles of Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PrinciplesOfEvaluation.html)

Comment: @Sasha As I understand in such cases as for example `a + b` when `a` and `b` are undefined *Mathematica* has some rules to be applied to this expression and infinite evaluation does no occur because it also checks whether applying the rules changes the expression. [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation.html) is stated: "*Mathematica* may think that the evaluation is finished because the expression did not change." How *Mathematica* determines that the expression did not change?

Comment: @Sasha I just realized that the statement ["*Mathematica* may think that the evaluation is finished because the expression did not change."](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation.html) is probably about *pattern rule* expression, not about the result of the evaluation. It is just an ambiguous statement.

Comment: You can get the same performance as the "left" case if you use standard evaluation instead of "ReplaceRepeated": `loop@{t_,h_}:=(i++;loop@t);Block[{$RecursionLimit=Infinity},Timing[i=0;loop@right;i]]`

Comment: @WReach Indeed, which is why I was quite surprised to see the massive slowdown with `ReplaceRepeated`; I had not considered the traversal path of comparison.